# Method does not invoked on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to create small application which can be used over Mac OS X 10.8.

On Mac OS X Mavericks and on Mac OS X Yosemite, my application work well but on Mac OS X 10.8, main method of my application does not invoked.  To be exact, the method seems to be invoked momentary, but soon after killed with alert sound.
I know that Mac OS X 10.8 is a bit strict than the OS after it.  But I think there are something wrong with my code which I can't find out.

My main method is OK because if it is called directly, it works fine without any problem.  But if I call it in the method of notification selector, the problem occur.

Here's my code.  I appreciate any kind of suggestion,thanks.

```
- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ( [[defaults objectForKey:@"aBookMark"] length] == 0 ) {
        [self getAudioCDPath];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(runEncodeAsyncWithNotify:)
                                                     name:NSWindowDidEndSheetNotification
                                                   object:self.window];
    } else {
        [self runEncodeAsync];
    }
}

/* This method have problem */
-(void)runEncodeAsyncWithNotify:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:NSWindowDidEndSheetNotification
                                                  object:self.window];
    encodingFlag = YES;
    [_start setEnabled: NO];
    [_stop  setEnabled: YES];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self encodeWithLAME];
    }];
}

/* This method does not have any problem */
-(void)runEncodeAsync {

    encodingFlag = YES;
    [_start setEnabled: NO];
    [_stop  setEnabled: YES];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self encodeWithLAME];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is to use `NSWindowDidEndSheetNotification` as sheet close notification.  `[self getAudioCDPath]`is a method which presents sheet OpenPanel and this have `completionHandler:` block in itself.
Since what I'd like to do is just to invoke `[self runEncodeAsync]`, I should write it in the `completionHandler:` block.  No need to use `NSWindowDidEndSheetNotification`.

So, here's modified code of `getAudioCDPath`.  Sorry I don't show it in the question.

```
[aPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {

    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {

        NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSURL *aDirURL = [[aPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSData *bookmark = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        bookmark = [aDirURL bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
                     includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
                                      relativeToURL:nil
                                              error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error creating bookmark for URL (%@): %@", aDirURL, error);
        }

        [defaults setObject:bookmark forKey:@"aBookMark"];

        [self runEncodeAsync]; // I added this to invoke main method!!
    }
}];
```